# How to pass value to constructor of ViewModel - MVVM using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

I'm getting started with MVVM using Caliburn.Micro and the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k

The tutorial shows how to set up a `ShellView` and open one 'child' View at a time in a `<ContentControl>`. I have all of this working fine, but now I want to pass some parameters from one child view to the constructor of a new child view. My first child view is called `FindQuotaView` and the second is called `QuotaView`. Basically I want the `FindQuotaView` to take input and display the result on `QuotaView`. As the `<ContentControl>` is in the `ShellView`, I figure I need `FindQuotaView` to "ask" the `ShellView` to load `QuotaView`.

After some searching I discovered the `EventAggregator` and I'm using that to notify the `ShellView` when I want to change the loaded view. At first I thought of raising two events, the first telling `ShellView` to load the `QuotaView` and the second to pass the parameters to the `QuotaView`. But my understanding from the video is that once the new view model is instantiated the existing view model is destroyed, so the second event wouldn't be raised. Instead I figured I would need to pass the parameters to the `ShellView` first. Here is what I have at the moment:

**Models**

```
public class LaunchRequest
{
    public LaunchRequest(Type viewModel, List<object> parameters)
    {
        ViewModel = (IScreen)viewModel;
        Parameters = parameters;
    }

    public IScreen ViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<object> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels**

ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<object>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        LoadViewModel(new LaunchRequest(typeof(FindQuotaViewModel), new List<object> { _eventAggregator }));
    }

    public void LoadViewModel(LaunchRequest launchRequest)
    {
        object[] args = { _eventAggregator, launchRequest.Parameters };
        ActivateItem(Activator.CreateInstance(launchRequest.ViewModel.GetType(), args));

        //Previous Method
        //switch (viewModel)
        //{
        //    case "FindQuota":
        //        ActivateItem(new FindQuotaViewModel(_eventAggregator));
        //        break;
        //    case "Quota":
        //        ActivateItem(new QuotaViewModel(_eventAggregator));
        //        break;
        //}

    }

    //Event Aggregator message handler
    public void Handle(object message)
    {
        LaunchRequest launchRequest = message as LaunchRequest;

        if (launchRequest != null)
        {
            LoadViewModel(launchRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

FindQuotaViewModel

```
class FindQuotaViewModel : Screen
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;


    public FindQuotaViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    private void FindUsersHomeShare(string username)
    {

        using (PowerShell cs = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //Unrelated code removed to shorten
            //string path = result from PowerShell

            //TODO: Pass the path to the QuotaViewModel
            _eventAggregator.PublishOnCurrentThread(new LaunchRequest(typeof(QuotaViewModel), new List<object> {path}));

        }

    }

}
```

QuotaViewModel

```
class QuotaViewModel : Screen
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public QuotaViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, object[] args)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

}
```

I'm currently getting an error casting `QuotaViewModel` to `IScreen` in the `LaunchRequest` model. I'm not quite sure why as the `QuotaViewModel` is derived from `Screen` which implements `IScreen`. I've also tried passing the parameter as `Screen` and `IScreen` but I can't get it working.

Could you please help me understand how to fix this, but also let me know if I'm going about this the right way? Am I over complicating things? Is there a simpler or better method to do this?

Comment: There is a nice article about Caliburn.Micro [basics](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition). To inject data into ViewModel constructor you can use any DI container or use built-in `SimpleContainer`, like in example from [GitHub](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/setup/Setup.WPF)

Comment: Thank you for the information. The Caliburn Micro link will definitely be helpful going forward. However I couldn't see an example in either of constructor injection. I've read up a little on DI and had a play around with that but I still can't get anything to work. I "think" I read that constructor injection isn't supported by the SimpleContainer in Caliburn Micro so started looking at AutoFac. But as you can see I've read so much I'm forgetting things and getting myself confused. Probably not helping that I'm quite tired now too lol Are you able to give me an example please?